# How can I set up rule for selectable FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to set up a rule for selectable attribute. The rule should be like this:
 `selectable attribute is true for future weeks, otherwise false`
However, I could not find how can I check dates in calendar option. I tried some ways but javascript does not accept these ways. Here is my current option. Any helps ?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        //some options
        //some options

            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,

            select: function (start, end) { 
                var title = loadRequired("ff8081815c776701015c7788151d06b4",
                    "activity",
                    "@Session["token"].ToString()");
                var eventData;
                if (title) {
                    eventData = {
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end
                    };
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
                }
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
            },
     });
```

});

Comment: what's the issue? In the "select" callback, check the start/end dates. If they're before the date that you want to allow, then don't continue to process the code, just return false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could be mistaken but because selectable is just a bool and doesn't accept a callback I don't think there is a nice way of doing this. I would probably set it to true and then catch it in the select callback.

In the select callback you could check if the selected date is in the future and if it is just call [unselect](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/unselect_method/) and return from the function.

Comment: I did your suggestion like below

Answer (score 0):

You can do either/both of these:

1) In the "select" callback, check the start/end dates. If they're before the date that you want to allow, then don't continue to process the code, just return false.

2) You could also set the validRange property so that events can't even be dragged onto the areas you choose to exclude: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/validRange/

Comment: Both options would provide quite a nice solutions, validRange seems like a nice option, I wasn't aware that.

Answer (score 0):

I checked situation on select atrr.

```
select: function (start, end) {
    var check = end.unix()*1000;
    var today = @weekdays[6]*1;


    if(today > check)
    { 
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');

    }else
    {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('select');
        var title = loadRequired("ff8081815c776701015c7788151d06b4",
            "activity",
            "@Session["token"].ToString()");
        var eventData;
        if (title) {
            eventData = {
                title: title,
                start: start,
                end: end
            };
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
        }

    }

},
```

now I can do what I want on functionality. However, I can still select the area on calendar, the area's color changed to blue, then it goes my check point, and if situation is false: unselect atrr is activated. 
Is there any way to do this ? Actually selectable attribute should not be true when the area is in the past and should be true on future weeks

Comment: this doesn't appear to actually answer the question, since you are still asking for things at the end, so don't post it as an answer. Please edit the original question if you have changes to your code. If the question is very different to the original, then make a new question. Also if the other answer have helped you to do what you need, consider marking them as accepted.